# Authorize WFS transaction before doing its job in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-geofence

I use GeoServer and internal Geofence.
I want  to validate a WFS transaction request:
If user has sufficient access (according to his rules in Geofence) then do something and if not, do something else!

```
if (user_has_permission):
    do_this()
else:
    do_that()
```

Dose GeoServer/Geofence have an API for this action?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a custom Java plugin for GeoServer, declaring in your application context either a:

- [TransactionCallback](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/wfs/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wfs/TransactionCallback.java), if you need to change the transaction contents before it's run, or just deny it
- [DispatcherCallback](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/ows/src/main/java/org/geoserver/ows/DispatcherCallback.java) if you want to capture the request before it even gets into the WFS machinery, and again alter it, or do something entirely different (e.g., manipulate a secondary table, log access, whatever).